# Mensaje desde sweetAlert desaparece enseguida y el formulario se envía

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Al dar click al botón, aparece la ventana modal de alert con el mensaje, pero desaparece en seguida, no se queda esperando a que el usuario lo lea o clickee como el alert de javascript.

```js
function validar() {
  swal("Buen trabajo!", "Clickeaste en el boton!", "success")
}
```

```html
<!-- SeetAlert -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- HTML -->
<form method="POST" action="proceso.php" onsubmit="validar()" target="_self">
  <input type="submit" name="btnProceso">
</form>
```

Comment: Por favor puedes colocar en ejemplo funcionando, edita tu pregunta y en el la opción de fragmento de código agrégalo para ver el error funcionado.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se soluciona añadiendo el *return* en el *onsubmit* del *form* , para que capture el false  retornado de la función y así no se produzca el envió del *form*

```js
function validar(e) {
  swal("Buen trabajo!", "Clickeaste en el boton!", "success");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form method="POST" action="proceso.php" onsubmit="return validar(event)" target="_self">
  <input type="submit" name="btnProceso">
</form>
```